# If $A$ is Hermitian and $U=(A-iI)(A+iI)^{−1}$ is unitary, then $U-I$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

I'm stuck on the $3$rd part of a question, the first part was proving $A-iI$ is invertible when $A$ is Hermitian, second was proving $U=(A-iI)(A+iI)^{−1}$ is unitary. Now I'm being asked to prove $U-I$ is invertible and I'm having a hard time. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered writing $I = (A + iI)(A + iI)^{-1}$ and manipulating $U - I$? If not, try it out and put your work in the body. Then we can see where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Because $A$ can be diagonalizable, $U$ and $U-I$ have specific forms. Then you can see $U-I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
  U-I&=(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}-I \\
     &=(A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1}-(A+iI)(A+iI)^{-1} \\
     &=(A-iI-A-iI)(A+iI)^{-1} \\
     &= -2iI(A-iI)^{-1}
\end{align}
$$